# Why do I get a 30 second preview when requesting Flow radio for free users?

Tags: deezer

When streaming a single track on Deezer from the server side, how can Deezer recognize that this track came from Flow radio and therefore give a full streaming url for a free user? I seem to always receive a 30 second preview for free users, which we would like to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

For the api to know that the track is within the subset of of a radio station (vs an on demand track), the api call needs to include the id of the station from which it came:

https://api.deezer.com/streaming_url.php?access_token=xxxx&radio_id=yyy&track_id=zzz

rather than simply:

https://api.deezer.com/streaming_url.php?access_token=xxxx&track_id=zzz

Comment: So is it possible to play full flow track for freemium users?